# Fork all repositories from a github user

Tags: github

Assume a case where one has a GitHub account and maintain multiple repositories. In an unfortunate scenario, the account is hacked and all the account recovery options are blocked. There is an immediate need to fork all repositories just to avoid a case where all repositories are removed.

If the user has massive number of repositories, it gets difficult to go to individual pages and fork all the repositories manually. How to tackle this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below javascript solution would work from the browser. Access any page on the GitHub user's profile whose repositories need to be forked. Open firebug console and execute the above javascript.

https://gist.github.com/techpavan/a35e3b603249871e0578c55d58c2b7e0

This was built and tested with Firefox 50.1.0 - An attempt to create a bookmarklet failed due to content security policy.

Note: This was originally asked by a SO user at https://stackoverflow.com/q/41355196/3940047 - the question was closed as it was unclear, it was not removed from hold even after a few edits to rephrase. Let me know in comments if the above explanation needs any improvement.